# TEXMAKER when compiling gives me error misplaced alignment

Tags: tables, errors

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> ...d/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-78751524824&
partnerID=40&md5=4144bdb06...
l.76 ...D=40&md5=4144bdb064f723bb3e27d5ff60673d79}
```

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Escape the ampersand. It's a special character used in tables.

Comment: @SeanAllred these things are tricky, it's a duplicate problem (and duplicate answer) but the way the question is phrased is different, It's not "how do I type this special character" it's "what does this error mean" If the OP had spotted that `&` was special the question wouldn't have arisen, which means they are unlikely to find the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

texmaker is just the editor, the error comes from TeX. You have used `&` which is reserved for marking table cells (alignment tabs) to get a `&` in text you need `\&` (or better use the `url` package).